# Процент соответствия слова выбранному языку

Tags: алгоритм, api, естественный-язык

Здравствуйте. У меня есть пять языков: английский, португальский, испанский, русский, болгарский. Когда пользователь вводит слово, я должен определить процент соответствия этого слова всем языкам. Например, вводится слово энциклопедия и мне выдаёт результат: русский - 99%, болгарский 87%, испанский - 3%, английский - 3%, португальский - 2%. Числа я с потолка взял. Просмотрел уже кучу api, но все они просто определяют язык текста и некоторые выдают % соответствия этому языку. А мне надо именно всем этим пяти языкам. Помогите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Можно написать самому :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, самому - это сопоставлять буковки с алфавитом? Если так, то это же совсем глупый анализ будет.

Comment: @VostokSisters, и как Вы сможете найти процент соответствия? Просто определить язык слова Вам первая же апишка сможет

Comment: @andreycha мне желательно использовать api и я не совсем понимаю, какие ставить теги

Comment: @Tabigon, по алфавиту - как? Просто проверять буквы и засчитывать баллы к конкретному счетчику совпадения буквы с алфавитом (учитывая одинаковые на вид буквы разных алфавитов), затем считается процент соответствия. Это легко. Но тупо. Нельзя такое делать. Если реализовывать нормально, то это большая задача.

Comment: @VostokSisters, вот и я про то же. Поэтому я хочу использовать api, т.к.  недостаточно времени придумывать свой полноценный алгоритм

Comment: @Tabigon, а это смотря какая задача и к какому сервису ты это делаешь. Способ, что я описал, хорош всем, если заказчики - не лингвисты и в нем не требуется определять морфологию по процентам)

Comment: @VostokSisters, даже если и делать это, то мне придётся обращаться в бд этих пяти языков, каким-нибудь способом искать похожие слова и подсчитывать %. И это ещё не учитывая того, что могут быть похожие слова в одном языке и как тогда искать %?

Comment: Всё решается частотным анализом. Дерём слово (с пробелами по краям) на пересекающиеся куски по 1, 2 и 3 буквы и смотрим, как часто в языках встречаются такие сочетания. Нужен только словарь с частотами, а там уж допилить не должно быть большой проблемой. Да, можно ещё частоту длин слов использовать.

Comment: Спасибо за теги :) Мне желательно api, т.к. времени не очень много на то, чтобы сделать. Но алгоритмы тоже стоит, мало ли апишку не найду нужную. Тогда придётся самому пилить

Answer (score 1):

Для слова - можно вычислить [расстояния Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) от него до каждого слова в словаре, связать с каждым из них апостериорную вероятность ошибки (для нормального закона распределения ошибки - по закону Стьюдента), после чего воспользоваться формулами вероятностей для суммы событий.

Для фразы - можно воспользоваться формулой вероятностей для произведения ошибок в словах.

Answer (score 0):

Сопоставить с алфавитом.(Желательно именно уникальные символы) в некоторых языках коды символов могут повторятся.

Подредактированя версия от @VostokSisters

Comment: Проблема не в определении языка, повторюсь, с этим справится любая апишка. Проблема определить соответствие слова каждому из пяти языков. Есть немного дурная идея сравнивать слово с каждым словом из языка, проводить проверку каким-нибудь алгоритмом, определять % соответствия слову и потом выбирать самый большой процент, как % соответствия языку. Но это какие затраты на ресурсы...

Comment: А почему не использовать топорный метод просмотр алфавита для таких языков как английский, португальский, испанский, русский, болгарский я думаю вполне будет работать?(если было бы больше языков возможно и не работало бы). Вариант с словарем тоже в прицепе не плох когда будут существовать варианты 50 на 50 можно его использовать.

Comment: В итоге сделал, как описали Вы. Составил 5 алфавитов и сравнивал каждое слово с каждым алфавитом. + учитывал пару правил, которые нашёл (например, в болгарском "ъ" мог быть в конце слова и между двумя согласными, а в русском такого нету).

Comment: @Tabigon если тестили, как результат? Моя основной посыл в том что для 5 языков не надо городить огород(в отличии от скажем 100 языках как в гугл траслейт к примеру).